# Differentiating quaternions

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

This question isn't completely well-formed, but I hope someone can still offer some insight on it. Thinking about how complex manifolds are in some sense an analogue of real manifolds when $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{C}$ and "smooth" is replaced by "holomorphic", I'm wondering:

1) Are there other types of manifolds that people study, based on other fields?

2) Relating to the above, what does analysis look like on these other fields (or other algebraic structures)? Are there results on what types of algebraic structures admit a kind of differentiation like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know enough to make an answer, but I can comment that yes, you can do analysis on what are called $p$-adic fields.  There's a big difference; through; $p$-adic fields are totally disconnected.  Staying with in the smooth category but losing the "field" part of your question; manifolds can have quaternionic or even octonionic structures on their tangent bundles.

Comment: The quaternions are a division algebra, not a field, because they aren't commutative. Nevertheless, see the 1973 paper by Deavours, "The Quaternion Calculus," in the American Mathematical Monthly. For another direction of generalization, you have Banach and Frechet manifolds which are modeled not on finite dimensional powers of R or C but on (generally infinite dimensional) Banach and Frechet spaces. These ideas all deal with topological vector spaces. For still another (more strictly algebraic) direction, see the notion of a derivation on an algebra, important in differential Galois theory.